creating OpenAPI documentation where some fields are Generics
In my example im using flask_openapi3 as my web framework.
I have a bunch of endpoints that are meant to return 2 components in their response: one is the same for all endpoints (metadata) and the other is specific to the endpoint.  I use Generics to define the 2nd (specific) part of the response, and it obviously doesnt generate appropriate documentation: OpenAPI just shows generic name in the schema.  I am looking for a way to actually replace generic type with specific type in the documentation.  See below:
my model:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import TypeVar
from m_info import AppInfo

T = TypeVar('T')

class Response(BaseModel):
    metadata: AppInfo = Field(None, alias="Metadata", description="Application Information") #same for all endpoints
    app_response:T = Field(None, alias="Application Response", description="Application Response") #different for all endpoints

my endpoint definition:
from flask_openapi3 import OpenAPI
from m_resp import Response

app = OpenAPI(__name__)

@app.get('/myendpoint', responses={200:Response}
def get_stuff():
    response = Response()    
    response.metadata = _get_app_info() #returns metadata
    response.app_response = _get_specific_response() #returns some specific type AppResponse1
    return response.dict(), 200

OpenAPI definition of response form this endpoint looks like this:
{
    "Application Response": "?",
    "Metadata": 
    {
        "Application Info": 
            {"Info":"string"}
    }
}

What do i have to do to change "Application Response": "?" in OpenAPI definition to "Application Response": AppResponse1
